# Accumulated normalized fitness

Tags: normalization, genetic-algorithm

I'm building a genetic algorithm and I stumbled on this:

> Accumulated normalized fitness values are computed (the accumulated
>   fitness value of an individual is the sum of its own fitness value
>   plus the fitness values of all the previous individuals). The
>   accumulated fitness of the last individual should be 1 (otherwise
>   something went wrong in the normalization step).
>   [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_(genetic_algorithm))

Could anyone explain why should I do it? What do I gain with this kind of normalization?

I already have a normalized fitness score ( I'm using gene_score/total_scores ), which gives me a sum of all the scores equal to 1. With that I can sort the genes from best to worst and do any kind of recombination / crossover.

Answer (score 0):

The accumulated normalized fitness is the cumulative sum of the normalized fitnesses of each individual.

Example: you have individuals with fitnesses 2, 1, and 7. Their normalized fitnesses are 0.2, 0.1 and 0.7. Their accumulated fitnesses are then 0.2, 0.3 and 1. The order may differ but it has no effect on the selection procedure.

The accumulated fitness allows you to do the selection (of one individual) with a single randomly generated number.

If your fitness is already normalized, further normalization will, of course, do nothing and you can safely skip this step and proceed to the accumulation.

There are also other selection techniques like ranking selection or tournament selection where no normalization and accumulation is needed.

Comment: In the step 1 of the same article it says to normalize the scores(using the method I'm already using), hence the question, why further normalziation if you already have a normalized data?

Comment: I understand how it is done, what I don't understand is why do this. If I have a random number between 0 and 1 to select the gene, I can make a list of all the genes that are >= to this number and then pick one at random. Is doing this accumulation process saving computation time?

Comment: No, you can't just check if the generated number n is greater than some normalized fitness f. What if, in my example, you would generate 0.9? That is greater than all the normalized fitnesses. You need to sum them up so that every generated number hits some individual. Besides, the cumulative fitnesses are always sorted so you can do binary search to find the corresponding individual. You could use your approach if you didn't normalize by the total score but by the maximum score but then you can't do the binary search or sort the population which would be an extra O(n log n) operation.

Comment: For the first part, I could use some kind of max score and min score, and generating the number between those two, so the 0.9 won't appear. About the binary search, I don't know what is this. I'll look for it.

Comment: Ok, I understand what binary search is, but I don't see why would I need to use it in this case, if I have a sorted array of individuals(which is also required for a binary search), I can access them by it's index, like If I want the top 10 rated, I just get them from this list, I don't need to know the exactly score of that individual.